# Large javascript files truncated in Opera when running on localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, opera

As per the title, when viewing a site I'm working on in Opera, running from localhost, large script files (those over about 500k) get truncated and then fire off an error such as:

```
Syntax error at line 8 while loading: expected expression, got <end of file>
```

No other browser causes this behaviour. If I load the file from a CDN instead (i.e. an external site) it works fine. Download the content from the CDN, add it to the project and reference on localhost and blam, it explodes.

Any ideas what causes this behaviour and if there's a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, though I have never seen this happen personally.

Does the file end with a line break? It is a known issue that user scripts may fail if they are not terminated by a LF or CRLF.